# Styling markers from GeoJSON based on non-string feature properties in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

as the title suggests, I would like to style some markers stored in a GeoJSON file. In each feature, I saved a "rotate": some_integer, based on how I want to rotate the marker.

In the stylejson in Mapbox I wrote the following style for the markers:

```
    {
        "id": "markers_test",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "markers_test",
        "layout": {
            "symbol-placement": "point",
            "icon-image": "marker_{style_id}",
            "icon-rotate": "{rotate}",
            "text-field": "{name}",
            "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold"],
            "text-anchor": "top-left",
            "text-padding": 20,
            "text-size": 10,
            "text-optional": true
        },
        "paint": {
            "text-color": "#dddddd",                
            "text-halo-color": "#0000ff",
            "text-halo-width": 1,
            "text-halo-blur": 1
        }
    }
```

Setting the correct name and icon works flawlessly, but as soon as I try to set up rotate, it crashes saying the value should be a number, not a string. Only - how do i reference a property of a feature outside a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{token}` syntax only works for `text-field` and `icon-image`. For all other properties you must use the [property function syntax](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#types-function).

```
{
    "id": "markers_test",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "markers_test",
    "layout": {
        "symbol-placement": "point",
        "icon-image": "marker_{style_id}",
        "icon-rotate": {
            "property": "rotate",
            "stops": [[0, 0], [365, 365]]
        },
        "text-field": "{name}",
        "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold"],
        "text-anchor": "top-left",
        "text-padding": 20,
        "text-size": 10,
        "text-optional": true
    },
    "paint": {
        "text-color": "#dddddd",                
        "text-halo-color": "#0000ff",
        "text-halo-width": 1,
        "text-halo-blur": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I missed that one, thanks.

One more question: is it also possible to pull enum values from geojson? For example: "icon-rotation-alignment": "{icon-rotation-alignment}", - this does not work. It expects either "map" or "viewport", but does not accept either string from the feature property.

Comment: The `{token}` syntax only works for text-field and icon-image. For all other properties you must use the property function syntax. See the `categorical` function type. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-function